# iPad Retina - iPad uses the iPhone retina images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, retina-display

This is a little bit weird. Now, I am developing an app that's universal. However, I don't provide images for the iPad retina (iPad 3 and 4), but still retina images available for the iPhone. Now, the app uses the retina images of iPhone on iPad 3 and 4 instead of using the non retina, yet with correct size, iPad images.

To clear this out:
- iPad 1 and 2 uses the iPad non retina images (normal).
- iPad 3 & 4 uses the iPhone retina images instead of the iPad non retina images!

I tried a solution where I renamed the iPhone retina images so that it will end with ~iphone@2x. This fixes the issue on the iPad 3 and 4 but now the iPhone 4, 4s & 5 uses the non retina images!

Comment: adding ~iphone to your image name will point to normal image.. isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, you got it the other way around. It should be `myimage@2x~iphone.png`.